# Por que um array em javascript continua com o mesmo tamanho mesmo quando usamos delete?

Tags: javascript

Estava fazendo uns testes no `javascript` e percebi que quando uso a função `delete` num índice de um `array`, o `array` continua com o mesmo tamanho.

Exemplo:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

delete a[1]

console.log(a.length); // Imprime 3
```

Por que isso acontece?

Comment: O `delete` apenas remove o valor atribuído. É uma questão de estrutura de dados. Um `array` é uma sequência limitada e fixa de posições lainhadas em memória. Se você quiser manipular uma lista deve utilizar uma lista encadeada, não presente nativamente no JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `delete` somente seta o valor do index passado do array para `undefined`.

```
delete a[1];
console.log(a); //[1,undefined,3]
```

Para remover um índice do array você pode utilizar o [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
a.splice(1,1); //vai retornar o indice removido [2]
console.log(a); //[1,3]
```

Comment: Que interessante, mesmo que o elemento deletado seja o último o tamanho continua sendo `3`! Enquanto que na atribuição o `length` se atualiza (ex.: `a[10] = 4` faz o `length` se tornar `11`). Essa é mais uma esquisitisse de JavaScript que eu não conhecia...